# Can anyone explain what the numbers at the top of this IP Header diagram represent?

Tags: ip, tcp

[image: ip header diagram]

… and what is the significance of the grouping?

many thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to give us the context and from where this diagram came.

Answer (score 1):

That table seems to be mangled somehow...

From the fields *version* and *IHL* you can tell that those numbers indicate the bits for those fields.

For *type of service* that continues but the first digit of the two-digit numbers is somehow placed in the upper half of the column header - so the indicated bits or 8 through 11 and 12 through 15. That scheme continues with 16-19, 20-23, 24-27, 28-31.